# Android Layout Editor missing up and down controls

Tags: android

The latest xml layout editor is missing the up and down controls (where you can move Views around the xml hierarchy), now I can't move layouts into another LinearLayout.  Drag and drop simply does not work.

Where have they gone?  What is the new way of doing this?

Comment: Where have all the features gone. New release coming. (repeat) Gone to bugs, every one.  When will they ever learn?  Oh, when will they eeeveerrr learn.   Seriously, yes 2.3 seems to have some inconsistent functionality that looks like a bug fix candidate.  I see it on my Linux distribution as well.

Answer (score 0):

They broke it in the plugin ADT 8.0.1. see:

[link text](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13042)

You can get the previous plugin by trying

[link text](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-8.0.0.zip)

The link's not shown on the developer.android pages but it does work. This version has its own bugs but I believe that the arrows are still there.

Comment: I uninstalled 8.0.1 and installed 8.0.0 but it did not have the arrows either

Answer (score 0):

Oh, in case you have always used the GUI version, the layout window is tabbed on the bottom.  You can see and edit the raw XML file from the "main.xml" tab.  Once you add the basic tag for a new a new layout or widget, you can either edit the XML source or switch back to the Graphic Layout tab, right click on the widget in the rightmost pane, and set properties.